# Cant delete file created by the java Transformer

Tags: java, xml

I am using the Transformer class in java in the following way -

```
1   Transformer transformerFinal = tFactory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(finalStylesheet));
2   transformerFinal.setParameter("Date", sdf.format(myDate));
3   transformerFinal.transform(new StreamSource(tempFilename), new StreamResult(new FileOutputStream(finalFilename)));
```

And then I want to delete this source file which was used for the transforming.

```
4       File fileToDelete = new File(tempFilename);                    
5       fileToDelete.delete();
```

It doesnt work, I mean the file doesnt get deleted.
But if at `line 3` I pass a local variable of the o/p stream viz.

```
1   FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(finalFilename);
4   transformerFinal.transform(new StreamSource(tempFilename), new StreamResult(fos));
5   fos.close();
```

Now the delete function works and it does delete the file.
So, am I correct, when I conclude that the o/p stream is not closed implicitly during the `transform` process ? and hence I have to close the stream explicitly.
Can anyone please share, if there is any other reason the file may not be getting deleted?

Please assume that all the variables have correct values.

Thank You.

> **Update**

One more thing I noticed.
I am calling this code from an another class, eg. -

```
public class ClassTwo {
   public void ameth(String tempFilename) {
     // the above mentioned transformation code
   }
}

1   public class ClassOne {
2       public void method1() {
3           ClassTwo ct = new ClassTwo();
4           ct.ameth("tempFilename1");
5           ct.ameth("tempFilename2");
6       }
7   }
```

Here, When I didn't explicitly close the stream, it did delete the `tempFilename2` but not the `tempFilename1`.
Any idea, why it behaves so?

Comment: @adarshr: The line-numbers disable the ability to simply copy+paste the code from here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're right: You can't delete a file that is still open. Due to an old bug in the Java API, the `delete()` can't tell you why -- it can only return a `boolean` result.

The reason for this behavior is that Java can't automatically clean up system resource other than heap memory. So we end up with the problem: Who can safely close the file? Maybe the transformation isn't complete, yet. Or you need to write a header+footer in the same stream.

So if **you** create a stream, **you** always have to close it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. If I understand you correctly, you are saying that not closing the stream in the `transform()` is on purpose and has been left to the user to make sure of that for safety reasons. Fair enough. But then, I feel it should have been mentioned in the Java docs.

Comment: @Swift-Tuttle: It's probably mentioned in the standard Java I/O API somewhere. Since everyone does it this way, there is no need to mention it over and over again.

Comment: Thank you. I have updated the question with something that I noticed, if possible can you please comment.

Comment: It's really hard to say without more information. Is that Linux, Mac or Windows? On Windows, maybe you had the file open in an editor. Are threads involved? Maybe the GC ran and collected the lock...

Comment: Its on Windows XP. There is no explicit Threading involved, just a plain java program. I will look around and have a run again and try to find if I can replicate. Thanks a lot again.